# How do I change the color of GUI in Java, for example the way spotify has their desktop app in color of blackish/grey?

Tags: java, user-interface

I wanted to create a desktop app for simple use, however I want to learn change the theme and look of the app. I want the app to look like Spotify in a way. How should I code this and are there any libraries available ?

Answer (score 1):

This will depend on the framework you intend to use.  In Swing, you would modify the [look and feel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/index.html) and depending on what you wanted to achieve, you would either modify the properties or consider making your own.

In JavaFX, you can modify the look and feel via CSS directly, [for example](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/css_tutorial/jfxpub-css_tutorial.htm)